# Unable to use apache-ldap-api with grails 2.2

Tags: ldap, grails-2.0

I am trying to use apache-ldap-api with grails 2.2 . The latest version of the api on their website is 1.0.0-M15 , but maven repo has upto 1.0.0-M13 . So I decided to use M13 first by adding a dependency to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    runtime(
        [group: 'org.apache.directory.shared', name: 'apache-ldap-api', version: '1.0.0-M13']
    )
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
}
```

Grails downloaded the dependency alright, but when I try to use the API in the code such as:

```
import org.apache.directory.groovyldap.LDAP

LDAP.newInstance(...)
```

I get a compile error :

```
LdapController.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class org.apache.directory.groovyldap.LDAP
  @ line 2, column 1.
import org.apache.directory.groovyldap.LDAP
^
1 error
```

The compiler lets me import 'org.apache.directory.groovyldap.*' but then again, the call to 'LDAP.newInstance()' throws an exception.
I also tried manually dropping the 1.0.0-M15 version in my /lib folder and running 'grails compile --refresh-dependencies' without any luck. Any ideas if I am doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I received the following response from api@directory.apache.org mailing list - "I don't think the existing groovy code works out of box cause a lot of things were changed" . However, there has been no word on what needs to tweaked to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

1 run this grails compile --refresh-dependencies
2 change LDAP.newInstance(...) into new LDAP

This is how it works for me

Comment: i also had to do compile as opposed to runtime, if you plan on using the jar, alike Eduard.